# String or binary data would be truncated from sql query

Tags: c#

When I try Click button save it displays the following error

**Error**

> String or binary data would be truncated.

**Code:**

```
 var connectionString = new ConnectionString();

var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString.ViMS_LOCAL());
string query = "INSERT INTO  [Visitor.Profile] 
    (Name,NRIC,Address,StartVisit,Gender,VisitorType,PassNumber,PlateNumber,StatusId, Reason) VALUES `
    (@Name,@NRIC,@Address,@StartVisit,@Gender,@VisitorType,@PassNumber,@PlateNumber,@StatusId, @Reason)";`

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", VisitorName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NRIC", NRIC.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", Address.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartVisit", sd1.Text);

//Radiobutton 
if (Male.IsChecked == true) {
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", Male.Content);
}
if (Female.IsChecked == true) {
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", Female.Content);
}    
if (Ped.IsChecked == true) {
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VisitorType", Ped.Content);
}
if (Veh.IsChecked == true) {
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VisitorType", Veh.Content);
}

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PassNumber", PassNumber.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PlateNumber", PlateNumber.Text);

if (RadEnab1.IsChecked == true) {
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StatusId", RadEnab1.Content);
}
if (RadDis1.IsChecked == true) {
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StatusId", RadDis1.Content);
}

` //Combobox function`    
if (Reason.Text == "Meeting") {
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Reason", Reason.Text);
}
if (Reason.Text == "Delivery") {
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Reason", Reason.Text);
}
if (Reason.Text == "Pickup") {
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Reason", Reason.Text);
}


try {
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

} catch (Exception err) {

} finally {
    conn.Close();
}
vSuccess.Content = "* Visitor Register Success!";
//}
}
```

I try debug it,everything it ok,but when it go to "catch (Exception err)"it display error

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Check if the size of para meter in stored procedure is less than the size of data being passed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare the lengths of the Text you are passing to the command and the size of the column in DataBase.

If the length of the text you are passing is greater than the specified field size in database this error occurs.

Example :
In my Table-

FieldName Size

Name       nVarchar(10)

If You pass a name with length greater than 10 this error occurs.

Hope this helps. I am new to c# and I got this exception recently.

Comment: It work,I never realize that my StatusId is nvarchar(2) in database